# Primitive Roots of prime powers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In Alan Baker's book, he stated that if $g$ is a primitive root mod $p$, then we can find $x$ such that $g'=g+px$ is a primitive root for all prime powers.
However, I'm confused as he states: $g^{p-1}=1+py$ for some $y$ and by the binomial theorem $g'^{p-1}=1+pz$, where $$z=y+(p-1)g^{p-2}x(mod p).$$
This is a step that has caused confusion for me. It would be great if somebody can help explain why this is so.

Then, he states that since the coefficients of $x$ are not divisible by $p$ we can find $x$ such that $(z,p)=1$, which I agree. Now he writes $$(1+pz)^k=1+p^{k+1}z_k$$ where $(z_k,p)=1$, and this is yet another step that I cannot understand. 
The rest of the steps are rather easy to comprehend.

Comment: Also if somebody can recommend a set of notes or some book available online as a pdf as a reference for Number Theory it'll be great. Baker is simply too concise for me. Whenever I read 'plainly' and 'indeed', I can hear him mocking and me complaining that there's nothing plain or obvious there.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently if I was willing to put my hands down to compute I'd see that the first few terms of the binomial expansion were
$$(1+py)+(p-1)g^{p-2}px+kp^2x^2+....+p^{p-1}x^{p-1}$$
where if we extract the $p$ from all terms containing it we see this is just
$$1+p(y+(p-1)g^{p-2}x+kpx+....+p^{p-2}x^{p-2})$$
and denoting the term in the brackets by $z$ we see immediately that the result is true.

Seems like I will continue using Baker's book.